# While installing Android-EABI toolchain, can I overwrite files in /usr?

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I just downloaded the Android NDK and wanted to copy/install the GCC cross-compiler toolchain to */usr* folder (where I have other cross-compilers as well). These are the contents of the toolchain forlder:

```
$ ls
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 4 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:13:44 arm-linux-androideabi/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 carles carles 4,0K  2014-mar-01  01:57:40 bin/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:13:46 include/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 3 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:14:15 lib/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:14:24 lib32/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:14:15 lib64/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 3 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:13:46 libexec/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 3 carles carles 4,0K  2014-gen-16  18:14:24 share/
 20K -rw-r--r-- 1 carles carles  18K  2014-gen-16  18:14:24 COPYING
 28K -rw-r--r-- 1 carles carles  26K  2014-gen-16  18:14:24 COPYING.LIB
4,0K -rw-r--r-- 1 carles carles 2,6K  2014-gen-16  18:14:25 SOURCES
```

To install it in */usr* I just did this:

```
$ cp * /usr -uvir
```

And as a result I found out that there were some files conflicting with this copy. In particular, `cp` asks whether to overwrite the following files:

```
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/types.py»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/pretty_printers.py»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/__init__.py»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-o32-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/sparc-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-n32-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/ppc-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/amd64-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/i386-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/sparc64-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/gdb-syscalls.dtd»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/ppc64-linux.xml»? n
cp: voleu sobreescriure «/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-n64-linux.xml»? n
```

To which questions I always answered no. Now after doing a few `diff`s I've seen that while some of those files basically add extra lines to the ones I had, some of them, if not all, change small variables and names.

Do you think it's a good idea to overwrite them? If not, would `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` still work?

Comment: `/usr/local/` is at least a better place than `/usr/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to place binaries in a path they don't expect.

Quite a lot of packages compile the path given to the `./configure` command line somewhere into the executables, so they can find additional resources easily. So whether your gcc works or not is questionable.

The files you listed all belong to the *gdb* debugger. The XML data files should be safe to overwrite if these are indeed newer, but it may also be that you are using older versions then. The Python files should also be somewhat safe if the changes are minimal -- these concern mainly how variables are printed in the debugger; this may be useful for certain string types.

Neither of these groups should be critical for debugging, so either way should be fine.